# wtform attribute with arguments in jinja2

Tags: jinja2, wtforms

Using the wtforms 'form' object, I am dynamically creating HTML input fields by iterating over the dict 'fields' which contains some field ids:

```
{% for i in fields %}
     {{ form[i.id|string] }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I also want to pass some additional arguments such that it would be evaluated as:

```
{{ form.SomeFieldID(disabled="disabled") }}
```

Doing the following does not work:

```
{{ form[i.id|string ~ '(disabled="disabled")'] }} # Does not work!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to figure it out. Just do:

```
{{ form[i.id|string](disabled="disabled") }}
```